# Forcing(version 10) Firefox Reload

Tags: javascript, firefox

I googled

Firefox Force Reload and read / scanned the first 4 hits.

All say to use either `Control R` or `Control F5.`  Neither of these work for me.  The only way I I have been able to force a reload (of my javascript) is by re-starting.

I pull in 3 files CSS, HTM, and JS all by Ajax Post.  Oddly, the CSS and HTM reload but the .js is cached.

It's looks like the browser is checking file extensions of ajax posts and auto caching .js despite the reload method.

Is there a way to force a reload of .js.  I just double checked the above solutions and they do not work.

Furthermore, What is the mechanism that let's Firefox know when to cache and when to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force reload, press `Control + Shift + R`. This will empty the cache and reload all page elements.

Comment: Not to be obnoxious..but this does not work now...yesterday was chance...Firefox does what it wants with utter randomness...I'm hitting Control Shift R and my .js is not refreshing...or perhaps the networks...i.e. server and computers in between are doing some caching?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: Honestly, what I would do in your situation would be a complete reinstallation of FF. It sounds to me like there's an issue with FF itself. Also, have you tried using different browsers? Adding `shift` to the refresh shortcut(s) to enable forced reload is more or less universal.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're on a library computer. :P In that case I'd try a different browser or a different computer altogether.

Answer (score 4):

What I normally do is disable the caches built into firefox. Then all you have to do is refresh the page no special key strokes required.  To do this in your url bar enter about:config then find the settings browser.cache.disk.enable and browser.cache.memory.enable set them both to false and restart.  Problem solved forever.

[image]

Comment: I will remember this but I am on a library computer with no access.

Comment: AH, on windows, hitting Ctrl+F5 will force firefox to flush the cache

Comment: OH also, to answer the second part of your question, browser cache behavior is determined by HTTP response headers and ETAGS normally.  Heres a paper on it http://www.f5.com/pdf/white-papers/browser-behavior-wp.pdf

Comment: I tried to control caching by POST ajaxing in all my static data...but the browser controls ajax post caching as well as regular GET and POST requests....I'll look into setting headers to stop this auto caching as I want control over caching myself...thanks++

Comment: Control Shift R does not work...is is possible that computers in between or the server is some how caching my .js file?

Comment: It is possible yes.  For example, they could be running squid or a similar product on the network to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

Open the javascript file in its own tab and control+F5 on that page. Then reload the page that uses the javascript file. That worked for me when all other methods failed.